# Making Cache access methods static

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, static

In ASP.NET, is there any reason not to make a set of functions that Add/Remove/Get from the Cache object Static?

Get() - just gets the item, no reason not to be static
Add(), Remove() - I've read that adding/deleting into the cache has it's own internal locking mechanism, so they can be static without me creating my own lock(){} wrapping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They can already be accessed in a static context through

`HttpRuntime.Cache`

The method of `HttpContext.Current.Cache` merely forwards to this call anyway, yet invoking the `HttpContext.Current.Cache` can cause runtime errors if it's not in the lifecycle where `HttpContext.Current` is available.

**Answering your question:**

Yes you could use this to handle that. You would have something like

```
public static class StaticCache
{

    public static Add(object obj)
    {        
        try {            
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(obj);            
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            //log or something            
        }        
    }    
}
```

And usage would be similar to

`StaticCache.Add("bob");`

Comment: Are you saying they can be static since HttpRuntime.Cache calls are static?  My question was about putting the Cache calls in methods so that I can do logging, error checking, change expiration times as needed, etc.

Comment: Wow, did not know this existed. I have always just used `HttpContext.Current.Cache` for accessing it statically.